# How do i hide dropdown field through a checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use a checkbox to hide dropdowns through it
when one checkbox is tick one  drop down should open and the next should have its visibility gone

Here is the code:

```html
  Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(child:
                            CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                  getTranslated(context,"facility"),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize:14
                                  )),
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, value: firstCheck,                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                firstCheck = value;
                                secondCheck = !value;
                              });
                            },
                            ),
                            ),

                            Expanded(child:
                            CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                  getTranslated(context, "community"),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize:14
                                  )),
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, value: secondCheck,                     onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                firstCheck = !value;
                                secondCheck =value;
                              });
                            },
                            ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: DropDownWidget(
                                list: ["xyxy","abb"],
                                data:selectFacility,
                                hint: getTranslated(context, "select"),
                                heading: getTranslated(context, "select_facility"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        
                         Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: DropDownWidget(
                                list: ["asdas","asdsad","asdsa"],
                                data: selectCommunity,
                                hint: getTranslated(context, "select"),
                                heading: getTranslated(context, "select_community"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

When facility checkbox is ticked only facility dropdown should open and vice versa

Comment: You can use `firstCheck` and `secondCheck` boolean to control the rendering of items of DropdownWidget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean expression to control widget like below

```
fistCheck ? Row(
   children: [
      Expanded(
         child: DropDownWidget(
         list: ["asdas","asdsad","asdsa"],
         data: selectCommunity,
         hint: getTranslated(context, "select"),
         heading: getTranslated(context, "select_community"),
         ),
       ),
   ],
  ) : Container(),
```